# Swift 4 URLSession 422 Response with No Error

Tags: swift, urlsession

Using Swift 4, I call a RESTful API like this:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                if data != nil, let user = try? MyRequests.jsonDecoder.decode(User.self, from: data!){
                    completion(user)
                }
                else{
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
```

The response has a statusCode of 422, a failing code, but the error is nil. Why is this occurring?

Comment: https://restpatterns.mindtouch.us/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity

Comment: please check the url in postman and see what is the output.

Comment: You should be looking at the documentation of your API. It seems like the engineers behind that API didn't follow best practices and a status code that indicates an error doesn't necessarily come with an actual error message explaining the exact cause of the issue. There are no standards/rules that would require a REST API to do both, so for the question _"Why is this occurring?", the only people who can give a definitive answer are the ones who built that specific API.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I built the API. It's a 422 with an HTTP body that includes "errors". Regardless, the URLSession library should not be accepting a status code of 422 as a success in my opinion. That's the part I'm confused about.

Comment: And 422 is the default code used by some API backend frameworks to return errors - not just "network connection" errors.  Android parses them w/o any special workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` value returned by `URLSession.dataTask` is used to represent network errors (such as no internet connection, etc.). However, backend/API errors are not returned in this variable.

You need to parse the `data` variable if your backend is returning the more elaborate error message as the response body to see the exact cause of the issue. The built-in networking methods don't actually evaluate the HTTP status code, you'll need to do that manually.

Evaluating them at a system library would probably not be desirable, since it is not guaranteed that all APIs follow the HTTP status codes and hence evaluating them automatically could result in false success/error messages. Moreover, there's no standard part of an HTTP request/response for returning the error messages, so the automatic parsing of those could also prove to be problematic.